# Splitting a list into sublists using a for loop

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, pathlib

I have a list of files I get from doing a pathlib.glob(). From that list, I need to work with them in chunks depending on their extension (so first .1, then .2, etc.).

I can only get the first group of files to show up, and after that I keep getting empty lists. I know i can workround this issue by just changing my initial glob, but the fact that I'm not seeing the issue means I don't understand how something works under the hood, and I'd like some help figuring it out.

This is my first attempt using list comprehension:

```
Import sys, os
from pathlib import Path
folder = Path(os.getcwd())
files = folder.glob('*dat*')
for i in range(4):
    extension = '*.'+str(i+1)
    cat = [x for x in files if x.match(extension)]
    print(cat)
```

prints [files with .1] [] [] []

and I get the same output using filter

```
for i in range(4):
        extension = '.'+str(i+1)
        cat = list(filter(lambda x:str(x).endswith(extension), files))
```

Clearly I'm missing something but i dont know what.

Comment: So you basically want to filter out all the files with same extension, right? @Mauro

Comment: Yes, i needed to split them into different lists so i could work with them in batches, depending on their extension. I used a dictionary for this, but i had issues iterating over the files object. Solution is pinned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that it happens because `files` is a *generator*. So in the list comprehension at your first iteration of `for` loop, its contents are already consumed, and so at the subsequent iterations there is no more items left!

So you might want to make a list out of `files` first: try putting

```py
files = list(files)
```

just before the `for` loop.

Comment: This was indeed the issue. Thank you fot your explanation